# How to set the locale property to TableCalendar widget

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, locale

Flutter has a widget called [Table calendar](https://pub.dev/packages/table_calendar). I'm trying to use it but I need to get the locale language from the device, or at minimum can set my language. In the documentation they code at main file, but I'm in another then I can't reproduce the example.

This is what I tried until now:

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            TableCalendar(
              //locale: "pt_BR",
              initialCalendarFormat: CalendarFormat.month,
              calendarStyle: CalendarStyle(
                todayColor: CustomColors.goldMD,
                selectedColor: CustomColors.blackMD,
                todayStyle: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 18, color: CustomColors.white
......
```

If I uncomment the line 'locale' and run the app, it throws this error:

> Locale data has not been initialized, call initializeDateFormatting().

So.. I go to the `initState` method and write:

`initializeDateFormatting('pt_BR', null);` (it receives 2 args)

And the error keeps equal. What can I do to handle this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
In this case you do not need `initializeDateFormatting` 
Step 1: You can directly use `flutter_localizations` 
Step 2: In `TableCalendar` set `locale: Localizations.localeOf(context).languageCode`
You can see working demo switch between `en` and `fr`
code snippet

```
import 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart';

void main() {  
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      localizationsDelegates: [
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
      ],
      supportedLocales: [
        const Locale('en', ''), // English, no country code
        const Locale('ar', ''), // Arabic, no country code
        const Locale('fr', ''),
        const Locale('pt_BR', ''),
      ],
...
 Widget _buildTableCalendarWithBuilders() {
    print("current locale ${Localizations.localeOf(context).languageCode}");
    return TableCalendar(
      locale: Localizations.localeOf(context).languageCode,
```

`pubspec.yaml` for `flutter_localizations`

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations: # Add this line
    sdk: flutter # Add this line
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/date_symbol_data_local.dart';
import 'package:table_calendar/table_calendar.dart';
import 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart';

// Example holidays
final Map<DateTime, List> _holidays = {
  DateTime(2020, 1, 1): ['New Year\'s Day'],
  DateTime(2020, 1, 6): ['Epiphany'],
  DateTime(2020, 2, 14): ['Valentine\'s Day'],
  DateTime(2020, 4, 21): ['Easter Sunday'],
  DateTime(2020, 4, 22): ['Easter Monday'],
};

void main() {  
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      localizationsDelegates: [       
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,      
      ],
      supportedLocales: [
        const Locale('en', ''), // English, no country code
        const Locale('ar', ''), // Arabic, no country code
        const Locale('fr', ''),
        const Locale('pt_BR', ''),
      ],
      title: 'Table Calendar Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Table Calendar Demo'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  Map<DateTime, List> _events;
  List _selectedEvents;
  AnimationController _animationController;
  CalendarController _calendarController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    final _selectedDay = DateTime.now();

    _events = {
      _selectedDay.subtract(Duration(days: 30)): [
        'Event A0',
        'Event B0',
        'Event C0'
      ],
      _selectedDay.subtract(Duration(days: 27)): ['Event A1'],
      _selectedDay.subtract(Duration(days: 20)): [
        'Event A2',
        'Event B2',
        'Event C2',
        'Event D2'
      ],
      _selectedDay.subtract(Duration(days: 16)): ['Event A3', 'Event B3'],
      _selectedDay.subtract(Duration(days: 10)): [
        'Event A4',
        'Event B4',
        'Event C4'
      ],
      _selectedDay.subtract(Duration(days: 4)): [
        'Event A5',
        'Event B5',
        'Event C5'
      ],
      _selectedDay.subtract(Duration(days: 2)): ['Event A6', 'Event B6'],
      _selectedDay: ['Event A7', 'Event B7', 'Event C7', 'Event D7'],
      _selectedDay.add(Duration(days: 1)): [
        'Event A8',
        'Event B8',
        'Event C8',
        'Event D8'
      ],
      _selectedDay.add(Duration(days: 3)):
          Set.from(['Event A9', 'Event A9', 'Event B9']).toList(),
      _selectedDay.add(Duration(days: 7)): [
        'Event A10',
        'Event B10',
        'Event C10'
      ],
      _selectedDay.add(Duration(days: 11)): ['Event A11', 'Event B11'],
      _selectedDay.add(Duration(days: 17)): [
        'Event A12',
        'Event B12',
        'Event C12',
        'Event D12'
      ],
      _selectedDay.add(Duration(days: 22)): ['Event A13', 'Event B13'],
      _selectedDay.add(Duration(days: 26)): [
        'Event A14',
        'Event B14',
        'Event C14'
      ],
    };

    _selectedEvents = _events[_selectedDay] ?? [];
    _calendarController = CalendarController();

    _animationController = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 400),
    );

    _animationController.forward();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _animationController.dispose();
    _calendarController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _onDaySelected(DateTime day, List events, List holidays) {
    print('CALLBACK: _onDaySelected');
    setState(() {
      _selectedEvents = events;
    });
  }

  void _onVisibleDaysChanged(
      DateTime first, DateTime last, CalendarFormat format) {
    print('CALLBACK: _onVisibleDaysChanged');
  }

  void _onCalendarCreated(
      DateTime first, DateTime last, CalendarFormat format) {
    print('CALLBACK: _onCalendarCreated');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        children: <Widget>[
          // Switch out 2 lines below to play with TableCalendar's settings
          //-----------------------
          //_buildTableCalendar(),
          _buildTableCalendarWithBuilders(),
          const SizedBox(height: 8.0),
          _buildButtons(),
          const SizedBox(height: 8.0),
          Expanded(child: _buildEventList()),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  // Simple TableCalendar configuration (using Styles)
  Widget _buildTableCalendar() {
    return TableCalendar(
      calendarController: _calendarController,
      events: _events,
      holidays: _holidays,
      startingDayOfWeek: StartingDayOfWeek.monday,
      calendarStyle: CalendarStyle(
        selectedColor: Colors.deepOrange[400],
        todayColor: Colors.deepOrange[200],
        markersColor: Colors.brown[700],
        outsideDaysVisible: false,
      ),
      headerStyle: HeaderStyle(
        formatButtonTextStyle:
            TextStyle().copyWith(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 15.0),
        formatButtonDecoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.deepOrange[400],
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16.0),
        ),
      ),
      onDaySelected: _onDaySelected,
      onVisibleDaysChanged: _onVisibleDaysChanged,
      onCalendarCreated: _onCalendarCreated,
    );
  }

  // More advanced TableCalendar configuration (using Builders & Styles)
  Widget _buildTableCalendarWithBuilders() {
    print("current locale ${Localizations.localeOf(context).languageCode}");
    return TableCalendar(
      locale: Localizations.localeOf(context).languageCode, //'pl_PL',
      calendarController: _calendarController,
      events: _events,
      holidays: _holidays,
      initialCalendarFormat: CalendarFormat.month,
      formatAnimation: FormatAnimation.slide,
      startingDayOfWeek: StartingDayOfWeek.sunday,
      availableGestures: AvailableGestures.all,
      availableCalendarFormats: const {
        CalendarFormat.month: '',
        CalendarFormat.week: '',
      },
      calendarStyle: CalendarStyle(
        outsideDaysVisible: false,
        weekendStyle: TextStyle().copyWith(color: Colors.blue[800]),
        holidayStyle: TextStyle().copyWith(color: Colors.blue[800]),
      ),
      daysOfWeekStyle: DaysOfWeekStyle(
        weekendStyle: TextStyle().copyWith(color: Colors.blue[600]),
      ),
      headerStyle: HeaderStyle(
        centerHeaderTitle: true,
        formatButtonVisible: false,
      ),
      builders: CalendarBuilders(
        selectedDayBuilder: (context, date, _) {
          return FadeTransition(
            opacity: Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0).animate(_animationController),
            child: Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0, left: 6.0),
              color: Colors.deepOrange[300],
              width: 100,
              height: 100,
              child: Text(
                '${date.day}',
                style: TextStyle().copyWith(fontSize: 16.0),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
        todayDayBuilder: (context, date, _) {
          return Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0, left: 6.0),
            color: Colors.amber[400],
            width: 100,
            height: 100,
            child: Text(
              '${date.day}',
              style: TextStyle().copyWith(fontSize: 16.0),
            ),
          );
        },
        markersBuilder: (context, date, events, holidays) {
          final children = <Widget>[];

          if (events.isNotEmpty) {
            children.add(
              Positioned(
                right: 1,
                bottom: 1,
                child: _buildEventsMarker(date, events),
              ),
            );
          }

          if (holidays.isNotEmpty) {
            children.add(
              Positioned(
                right: -2,
                top: -2,
                child: _buildHolidaysMarker(),
              ),
            );
          }

          return children;
        },
      ),
      onDaySelected: (date, events, holidays) {
        _onDaySelected(date, events, holidays);
        _animationController.forward(from: 0.0);
      },
      onVisibleDaysChanged: _onVisibleDaysChanged,
      onCalendarCreated: _onCalendarCreated,
    );
  }

  Widget _buildEventsMarker(DateTime date, List events) {
    return AnimatedContainer(
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
        color: _calendarController.isSelected(date)
            ? Colors.brown[500]
            : _calendarController.isToday(date)
                ? Colors.brown[300]
                : Colors.blue[400],
      ),
      width: 16.0,
      height: 16.0,
      child: Center(
        child: Text(
          '${events.length}',
          style: TextStyle().copyWith(
            color: Colors.white,
            fontSize: 12.0,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildHolidaysMarker() {
    return Icon(
      Icons.add_box,
      size: 20.0,
      color: Colors.blueGrey[800],
    );
  }

  Widget _buildButtons() {
    final dateTime = _events.keys.elementAt(_events.length - 2);

    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: <Widget>[
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text('Month'),
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  _calendarController.setCalendarFormat(CalendarFormat.month);
                });
              },
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text('2 weeks'),
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  _calendarController
                      .setCalendarFormat(CalendarFormat.twoWeeks);
                });
              },
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text('Week'),
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  _calendarController.setCalendarFormat(CalendarFormat.week);
                });
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
        const SizedBox(height: 8.0),
        RaisedButton(
          child: Text(
              'Set day ${dateTime.day}-${dateTime.month}-${dateTime.year}'),
          onPressed: () {
            _calendarController.setSelectedDay(
              DateTime(dateTime.year, dateTime.month, dateTime.day),
              runCallback: true,
            );
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _buildEventList() {
    return ListView(
      children: _selectedEvents
          .map((event) => Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border.all(width: 0.8),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
                ),
                margin:
                    const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0, vertical: 4.0),
                child: ListTile(
                  title: Text(event.toString()),
                  onTap: () => print('$event tapped!'),
                ),
              ))
          .toList(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Firstly, thank you, but I dont understand you example properly.. there are stateless, stateful widgets.. I only need set the locale ptBR to the calendar changing a minimum the current code